# 2 routers, 2 ISP, 3 access points. Same Network

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp, wireless-access-point

I have the following situation: i've got 2 WIFI routers with different ISP's their config:

1st router's IP is 192.168.1.1 | DHCP Enabled 192.168.1.2-254 | Dlink DIR 825 ACF

2nd router's IP is 192.168.7.1 | DHCP Enabled 192.168.7.2-254 | TP-link WR740N

Also, I've got 3 AP (not really AP, they are just wifi routers working as AP, one of them is adsl modem, so they are just wifi switches, right??)

The problem: When you're trying to connect to these AP, all of these "Access Points" automatically get their IP adresses from TP-link router's range (192.168.7.2-254), if you disable TP-link they switch to Dlink's IP adresses(192.168.1.1-254).
How to make Access Point to take desired gateway (192.168.7.1 or 192.168.1.1)

All i want is to get 1 AP to work with Dlink. Right now they are all getting their internet from Tplink.

Comment: you could try limiting DHCP responses by filtering MAC address of the AP.

Comment: Will it just deny internet access to access points or it also wont give them dhcp adress

Comment: You can try Address Reservation setting under DHCP menu for TP-Link and Static DHCP under DHCP server configuration for D-Link. Also TP-Link has IP&MAC binding setting menu, which is essentially the same, but I do not understand why it is done in two places. Also MAC filter in D-Link seems not to be related to WiFi only according to documentation. Indeed TP-Link seems to have MAC filtering only for WiFi, although you can try it and check if it works with wired devices.

MAC filter should deny total access for the device, including ARP requests and DHCP address assignment.

Comment: If you are going to spend time on this, why not try to aggregate the connections together, then assign specific devices to specific gateways? You can fully utilize both isp connections, and the ap's can be isp agnostic this way...

Comment: I cannot assign gateways to AP, there's no such setting, idk why, these "AP" are just wifi routers, they dont have AP mode, i simply connected them to my LAN, they are working as "wifi switches" (i guess?). PC's are working fine with gateway i selected. its just these AP

Comment: Your comment makes me think you didn't fully understand what I'm trying to get across to you... This is a mis-configuration issue, and they way you are trying to get this to work is non-ideal. You have a little bit of reading to get through I think. Start with NAT tutorials, then learn the difference between bridging & cascading routers.

Comment: Also, look into using pfsense for the main router. You can use it to aggregate your two isp connections, then create ACLs to designate what devices leave each isp connection.

Comment: Thanks alot! I know im stupid and Its hard to write in english, i hope you understood my problem: 1 dhcp sever wins the race against another one, so when i connect to any of my AP i get the same gateway. I want to make ap to work with specific router.

Comment: I read a bit of everything, and you are so right! But I cannot afford pfsense devices right now nor "sophisticated" router. What i thought was to connect main router's LAN to routers' WAN ports (i've got 3 of them) and i get 3 separated networks (which is fine), but by doing that, all the connected devices would be behind 2 NATs, would that be a problem? i couldnt quite understood that, some say it might decrease speed, i havent tried it yet tho